# Wordpress - Change the theme if a custom field has a certain value

Tags: wordpress, themes

I have been trying to get wordpress to change the theme for certain posts not all.  The only unifying item for the posts that need the new theme is a custom field.  The custom field is set to 1 for all of these posts.  I have installed jonradio multiple themes but that is set up for all posts or none at all.  After I get the certain posts to change themes then I will need to set it up for some categories and jonradio Multiple Plugin can only be set up for 1 category or search parameter.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: why do you need to change themes entirely? Why not just use the template hierarchy and create a new layout?  As far as changing themes for the same wordpress install with different posts, that's not gonna happen. The current theme is saved in wp_settings. You can't activate multiple themes. You could do a multisite install and publish posts to different sites in a wordpress network based on some logic.... but it's a heck of a lot harder than just creating a few new page/post templates

Comment: Well I found the headspace 2 plugin which allows you to select what theme will work with each post while you are creating the post.  But that doesn't help me with all of the posts already in the database.  I'll have to write it up myself, I just thought I would ask, thanks for your help.